# e.keyCode in iOS Safari on keyup event

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

## Update

**I have been trying so far in the simulator along physical keyboard. That was causing the problem. However with soft keyboard it works as desired. `keyup` event has a well defined `keyCode`.**

---

Please find the code at [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJPBVy)

`<input type="text" id="test">`

`var test = document.getElementById('test');
   test.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
     alert(e.keyCode);
   });`

iOS safari display `0` as the keyCode for any key pressed (`keyup` event). Any pointer would be very helpful.

**Update**

`e.keyCode` as well as `e.which` works with `keypress` event, but I could not get it to work with `keyup` event.

Comment: `alert(e.keyCode || e.which);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`e.keyCode` is present in the `keyup` event in iOS safari, in actual device as well as simulator. 
However in **simulator**, if **physical keyboard** is used, `e.keyCode` is set to `zero`.[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`.

**Edit**: To normalize this value, you could use `e.keyCode || e.which`.

Comment: Thank you, did you try out the pen? Unfortunately it's not working with ``keyup`` event. ``e.keyCode`` as well as ``e.which`` works with ``keypress``, but I could not get it to work with ``keyup``

Comment: @sarbbottam It works with `keyup` on Chrome, Firefox, IE & iOS Safari : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByOOyJ

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have been trying in simulator along with the physical keyboard. Your solution works with soft keyboard. +1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with `keyup` and `keydown` by using `e.key` which returns the key pressed (e.g. `/` or `a`).

I was able to figure this out by inspecting the event object using the remote debugger.

I checked in the latest Chrome, Firefox, iOS Safari, and macOS Safari and they all report the key via `e.key`.

**Edit:**

`keyup` and `keydown` aren't working now. I think I glitched it with the remote debugger or something. I have, however, figured out an alternative solution which works for my use case.

I wanted to focus an input when `/` was pressed. I went with the above solution of binding to `keypress` but the key was entered into the input since the `keyup` event hadn't fired. Simply calling `e.preventDefault()` solved my issue nicely. I can still match on `e.key == '/'` with the `keypress` event too!